# catchable fatal error in passed argument (services)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to build a custom validator running as a service (mainly for getting the entity manager).

I followed the doc and some blog posts but can't make it working. I have this error

```
    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
D\AjaxBundle\Validator\Constraints\SelectTypeValidator::__construct() must implement 
interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given, called in 
/AJAX/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 67 and defined in 
/AJAX/src/D/AjaxBundle/Validator/Constraints/SelectTypeValidator.php line 14
```

SelectTypeValidator.php

```
namespace D\AjaxBundle\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SelectTypeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $om;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om=$om;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $fieldOne = $this->om->getRepository('DAjaxBundle:City')->findOneBy(array('id' =>
                $value->getId()));

        if ($fieldOne == null) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value->
                    getId()));
        }
    }
}
```

SelectType.php

```
namespace D\AjaxBundle\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator;

class SelectType extends Constraint
{
    public $message ='message';

    public function validateBy()
    {
        return 'SelectTypeValidator';
    }

    public function getRequiredOptions() 
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    d_ajax.validator.SelectTypeValidator:
        class: D\AjaxBundle\Validator\SelectTypeValidator
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: SelectTypeValidator }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your validation? It seems you're just checking it was persisted to the database

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter